# Shouldn't the temporary A(3) be destroyed before "Here" is printed?

Tags: c++, temporary, construction, destruction

Shouldn't the temporary `A(3)` be destroyed before "Here" gets printed?

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    int a;
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    A(int a) : a(a) { std::cout << "A(" << a << ")" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A() " << a << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    A a[2] = { A(1), A(2) }, A(3);
    std::cout << "Here" << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
A(1)
A(2)
A(3)
Here
~A() 3
~A() 2
~A() 1
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfee36e2b9bc7532)

Comment: No, the destructors are being evoked as soon as the object gets out of scope (i.e., when main's `}` is reached).

Comment: @101010 Isn't the temporary destroyed at the end of the declaration `A a[2] = { A(1), A(2) }, A(3);` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`A(3)` is not a temporary object, but an object of type `A` called `A`. It's the same logic as this:

```
A a[2] = { A(1), A(2) }, a2(3);
```

I didn't actually know you were allowed to do that.

Comment: you can do it, but after you did, you have to refer type `A` as `struct A` because just `A` would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

As an extension to @neil-kirk's reply the reason `A(3)` is not a temporary is that the original line

```
A a[2] = { A(1), A(2) }, A(3);
```

is really a shorthand declaration of two variables `a[]` and `A`

```
A a[2] = { A(1), A(2) };
A A(3);
```

similar to how you might do

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
```

or

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
```